# Moq Callback not working with 3 parameter method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to understand why the following unit test does not execute the callback. If I modify the code so that the UpdateWorklowInstanceState method only contains 2 parameters (Guid and IList), it works. However, something about having 3 parameters interferes.

What I mean by interferes is that the Callback doesn't appear to get executed. There's no error message. I expect to see the "Error Occurred" message but instead receive an "Element Updated" message which means the Callback did not populate the resultMessages with the NotificationMessage.

```
public void BusinessObjectReturnsErrorNotification_ReturnErrorMessage()
        {
            var workflowInstanceGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

            var workflowElementModel = new WorkflowElementModel
            {
                ElementName = "ValidName",
                WorkflowInstanceId = workflowInstanceGuid.ToString()
            };

            var workflowElementInstance = new WorkflowElementInstance
            {
                ElementName = workflowElementModel.ElementName,
                FullDescription = "Full Description",
                SummaryDescription = "Summary Description",
                RefTime = DateTime.Now,
                ElementType = "ElementType"
            };

            var mockWebApiBusinessObject = new Mock<IWebApiBusinessObject>();
            mockWebApiBusinessObject.Setup(m => m.UpdateWorkflowInstanceState(workflowInstanceGuid, workflowElementInstance, It.IsAny<List<NotificationMessage>>()))
                .Callback<Guid, WorkflowElementInstance, IList<NotificationMessage>>(
                    (workflowInstanceId, elementDetails, resultMessages) =>
                    {
                        resultMessages.Add(new NotificationMessage("An Error Occured!", MessageSeverity.Error));
                    });

            var controller = new WorkflowElementController(mockWebApiBusinessObject.Object);
            var result = controller.UpdateWorkflowElement(workflowElementModel);

            Assert.AreEqual("An Error Occured!", result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
```

Method under test:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UpdateWorkflowElement")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateWorkflowElement(WorkflowElementModel workflowElementModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || workflowElementModel == null)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        string responseMessage;

        if (workflowElementModel.RefTime == DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            workflowElementModel.RefTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        var resultMessages = new List<NotificationMessage>();
        var instanceId = new Guid();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workflowElementModel.WorkflowInstanceId) ||
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workflowElementModel.ElementName))
        {
            responseMessage = "WorkflowInstanceId or ElementName are null or empty";
        }
        else if (!Guid.TryParse(workflowElementModel.WorkflowInstanceId, out instanceId))
        {
            responseMessage = "WorkflowInstanceId is not a valid Guid";
        }
        else
        {
            var element = new WorkflowElementInstance
            {
                ElementName = workflowElementModel.ElementName,
                RefTime = workflowElementModel.RefTime,
                SummaryDescription = workflowElementModel.SummaryDescription ?? "",
                FullDescription = workflowElementModel.FullDescription ?? ""
            };

            _webApiBusinessObject.UpdateWorkflowInstanceState(instanceId, element, resultMessages);

            responseMessage = "Element Updated";
        }

        if (NotificationMessage.HasErrors(resultMessages))
        {
            responseMessage = resultMessages.Find(m => m.Status == MessageSeverity.Error).Message;
        }

        response.Content = new StringContent(responseMessage);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean interferes, what error message do you receive, what was the expected behavior versus the observed behavior?

Comment: What I mean by interferes is that the Callback doesn't appear to get executed. There's no error message. I expect to see the "Error Occurred" message but instead receive an "Element Updated" message which means the Callback did not populate the resultMessages with the NotificationMessage.

Comment: You should probably edit your question with the above.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Updated.

Comment: @rl-mdt you also have not shown the method under test so there is no telling if there is anything wrong with the logic of your code vs your expectations.

Comment: @Nkosi I have added the method under test.

Comment: @rl-mdt you are creating new instances of the parameters in the method under test, which would be different instance to the ones used in the setup. That is why the call back is not working. To prove it. use It.IsAny for all the parameters and it should work.

Comment: @Nkosi This worked, thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work in you case for 3 parameters because you are mixing the expression parameter types.

```
It.IsAny<List<NotificationMessage>>()
```

in the setup, as apposed to the

```
IList<NotificationMessage>
```

in the callback parameters.

That means the setup expression parameters does not match the callback expression parameters so the call back is not going to be called.

Stick with one type so either go with the `List<NotificationMessage>` for both

You are also creating new instances of the parameters in the method under test, which would be different instance to the ones used in the setup. That is why the call back is not working. To prove it. Use `It.IsAny<>()` for all the parameters and it should work

```
mockWebApiBusinessObject
    .Setup(m => m.UpdateWorkflowInstanceState(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<WorkflowElementInstance>(), It.IsAny<List<NotificationMessage>>()))
    .Callback<Guid, WorkflowElementInstance, List<NotificationMessage>>(
                (workflowInstanceId, elementDetails, resultMessages) =>
                {
                    resultMessages.Add(new NotificationMessage("An Error Occured!", MessageSeverity.Error));
                });
```

Or the more generic interface

```
mockWebApiBusinessObject
    .Setup(m => m.UpdateWorkflowInstanceState(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<WorkflowElementInstance>(), It.IsAny<IList<NotificationMessage>>()))
    .Callback<Guid, WorkflowElementInstance, IList<NotificationMessage>>(
                (workflowInstanceId, elementDetails, resultMessages) =>
                {
                    resultMessages.Add(new NotificationMessage("An Error Occured!", MessageSeverity.Error));
                });
```

You should also take some time and review [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.

Comment: This answer made it possible for me to find the issue I've been dealing with for hours!!! One of my parameters should have been an "It.IsAny<object>()" and I was setting it as "It.IsAny<object>()". Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Please consider updating at minor places in your unit test.
Add before mocking `IWebApiBusinessObject` object:

```
 List<NotificationMessage> messages = new List<NotificationMessage>();
```

Additionally, update `Callback` :

```
var mock = new Mock<IWebApiBusinessObject>();
            mock.
            Setup(m => m.UpdateWorkflowInstanceState(It.IsNotNull<Guid>(), It.IsNotNull<WorkflowElementInstance>(),It.IsAny<List<NotificationMessage>>() )).
            Callback(() => 
                {
                    messages.Add(new NotificationMessage("error msg", MessageSeverity.Severe));
                    messages.Add(new NotificationMessage("Ignore Message", MessageSeverity.Normal)); // this is optional... u can remove it if u want.
                });
```

And need to update the source code method `UpdateWorkflowElement(WorkflowElementModel model)` to

```
UpdateWorkflowElement(WorkflowElementModel model, List<NotificationMessage> messages);
```

Consider changes in unit test code calling `UpdateWorkflowElement` to

```
var result = controller.UpdateWorkflowElement(workflowElementModel, messages);
```

If I have understood your `UpdateWorkflowInstanceState()` method correctly, 
then you are using `IWebApiBusinessObject` to call `UpdateWorkflowInstanceState( , , )` method. 
When `UpdateWorkflowInstanceState( , , )` executes during unit testing, it fires the `Callback` in your unit test and adds messages in list of `NotificationMessage`.

Comment: I understand your suggestion but it's the UpdateWorkflowInstanceState method that returns the list of messages, not UpdateWorkflowElement. Note that if I modify UpdateWorkflowInstanceState to only accept 2 parameters (Guid and IList<NotificationMessage>) the callback works. I also tried it with just WorkflowElementInstance and IList<NotificationMessage> for parameters and it also works. Something about having 3 parameters is creating the problem.